# Python Rainflow counting how to set threshold?

Tags: python

I am using python to do fatigue calculations, and using the `rainflow` library. 
If I am running the code on an sample data series, i get all the cycles. I want to limit the number of cycles counted with a threshold. Example: I have a sine with amplitude 202, and a cosine with amplitude 50 and 10 times the sinus period, and an offset of 601. Then I get all the periods. I do not want periods lesser than 100. Is this possible with use of the library `rainflow` or `fatpack` to get the range with threshold?

```
import numpy as np
import rainflow

x = np.linspace(0, 40, 200)
y = 601.0 + 202.0 * np.sin(x) + 50.0 * np.cos(10*x)

print rainflow.count_cycles(y, ndigits=0)
```

Comment: Did you mean the first item returned from the result? Or you wanted to filter out based on `x`? I got result as `[(12.0, 1.0), (16.0, 1.0), ...]`

Comment: I do not want results lower than 100.

Comment: Will list comprehension do? `res = rainflow.count_cycles(y); res = [x for x in res if x[0]>100]?`